# Set conditional formatting on a column that depends on another cell's text (not value)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am making a shift calendar. I have it so my calendar dates are displayed with the day names and they are a formula so if I enter one date, the rest of the calendar changes to follow suit.

I want the columns to highlight yellow if the days are weekends. For example, if B1 has the text "Sat" or "Sun" I want the entire B column to turn yellow. But since the value is the numerical date and not the text "Sat" I don't know how to make the conditional formatting work. Do I need a script or is there a formula that could work?

Answer (score 4):

Since you use the date value, we have a nice [weekday()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985?hl=en) function we can make use of.

`weekday(*yourDate*,2)` will give you an integer from 1-7 counting from Monday. On the conditional formatting applied to your targetted range, we can then use the following custom formula to highlight weekends:

```
=weekday(B$1,2)>5
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to [Irin's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115095/142901), here is a formula that you can use for general situations.

```
=match(B$1,{"Sat","Sun"},0)
```

See [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) for documentation on `match`.

`{}` is the format to concatenate arrays. The operator `;` concatenates arrays of matching length vertically, ie. stacking rows; while `,` concatenates horizontally, ie. stacking columns. In this case, we are just creating a single row *ad hoc* comprising of the list of strings you would like to match to.

`{}` and the concatenation operations are convenient tools. It's nevertheless better for you have a place where you store all possible strings and use that array instead of the ad hoc `{"Sat","Sun"}`. You can then use data validation to ensure you are inputting the right string every time.

Besides `match`, you can also use [`find`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126) and obviously a combination of [`exact`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094073) and `or`.

---

For completeness, I shall also include a quick review on custom formula in Conditional Formatting.

Recall that with any custom formula in Conditional Formatting, you are always inputting a range and a formula relative to a single cell. The custom formula should always output a boolean value. The spreadsheet will automatically iterate the cell indices across your range.

Suppose your range is `A1:C3` and your formula depends on `B3`.  That means, when it comes to formatting, all cells in `A1:C3` should use the value in the cell 1 column to the right and 2 row below as the input of your formula. For example, if your formula is `isblank(B3)`. Then `C3` will depend on whether `D5` is blank.

On top of that, `$` operator works as usual.